# How to user trigger to update a column comparing with system date in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I wrote this trigger to update a certain column. The trigger I wrote is this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateotMark
BEFORE UPDATE
ON sBookBorrow
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(SYSDATE-to_date(etime)>15)
BEGIN
UPDATE otMark = 1;
END;
/
```

This is the first time I use trigger, so I have no idea what went wrong. Any ideas? Thanks everyone for your answer.

**UPDATE:** This is what I got in the console. What did I do wrong?
[image]

**UPDATE2**:Now it has a error message:ERROR at line 5:
ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification

Comment: What logic you want to implement? What result/error you've got?

Comment: I want to get the otmark to be 1 when system date is 15 days more than etime( which is a date ) It can't run, I have nothing.

Comment: What is `otmark`? A column or a table?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp a column in the table sBookBorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the data type of "etime"?

If date, you don't need to use "TO_DATE" function. ex.(SYSDATE - etime > 15)

If VARCHAR2, you need to put the format. ex. TO_DATE(etime,'YYYYMMDD')

However, use [SHOW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12041.htm) in SQLPlus will give you more information about error.

```
SHOW ERROR TRIGGER updateotMark;
```

Let try this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updateotMark
BEFORE UPDATE
ON sBookBorrow
FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (SYSDATE - NEW.etime > 15)
BEGIN
   :NEW.otmark := 1;
END;
```

Comment: No error with the trigger, but I'm getting a error message while creating the trigger: ERROR at line 5:
ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification

Comment: Try to use SYSDATE - NEW.etime > 15, please.

Comment: It worked with a warning saying Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

Comment: Could you try my code on my answer? just change "=" to ":=" .

Answer (score 0):

Just update the :new value

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateotMark
BEFORE UPDATE
ON sBookBorrow
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(SYSDATE-to_date(etime)>15)
BEGIN
:new.otmark = 1;
END;
```

Comment: I put a screenshot of my console in the update. Any idea why it happened?

Comment: I think you are getting the error message because you need to specify whether the etime you are using in "WHEN(SYSDATE-to_date(etime)>15)" is from new or old.